# How to show tab indicator at top of Tabs

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, androiddesignsupport

I followed [this tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout). I have made simple change that shows [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) at bottom of screen.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager_landing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs_landing"
        style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

**Problem:-**

`TabIndicator` is showing at bottom of screen working well,Now I want to show that `TabIndicator` at Top of Tabs rather than bottom.
Using custom layout we can do that as mentioned in tutorial but is there any xml attribute that will show `TabIndicator` at top ?

Comment: put your xml code. thx

Comment: @Fakher I have posted xml

Comment: @Nilesh Did you achieved this? I also wanna show tab indicator on top.

Comment: @NiteshKhatri No not by default , for Now i Have made custom layout  for that

Comment: Please refer the Solution from [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33810156/how-to-change-indicator-of-tablayout-to-top-from-bottom/45585007#45585007)

Answer (score 4):

Add this line to your TabLayout in XML

```
app:tabIndicatorGravity="top"
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
LinearLayout tabs = ((LinearLayout) tabLayout.getChildAt(0));

for (int position = 0; position < tabs.getChildCount(); position++) {
    LinearLayout item = ((LinearLayout) tabs.getChildAt(position));
    item.setRotationX(180);
}
```