# How to change indicator of tablayout to top from bottom?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I want to change indicator of tablayout from bottom to top.

my code

activity_tab.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"

        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        app:tabIndicatorColor="#000000"

        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

I want this result.

[image]

how to do

thx for ask me and sorry for bad english.

Comment: Please embed you image as picture without html tagging it. Also improve the quality of your text please!

Comment: ok , I'm sorry and I will edit it.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: I use smart tab layout library

Answer (score 36):

Don't use scale = -1 and things like that.

From XML you can use `app:tabIndicatorGravity="top"`

From code you can use `setSelectedTabIndicatorGravity(INDICATOR_GRAVITY_TOP)`

Comment: underrated, probably because it has been added recently to the standard library, but that's definitely the way to go, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 13):

It can be done by xml attribute, use `android:scaleY="-1"` in xml code. The view will flip vertically. Use the same method to correct the text and image used in tab title.

In xml file:

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:scaleY="-1"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
```

In Java code

```java
tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

// Adding the tabs using addTab() method
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Section 1"));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Section 2"));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Section 3"));
tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

TextView tv1 = (TextView)(((LinearLayout)((LinearLayout)tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(1));
tv1.setScaleY(-1);
TextView tv2 = (TextView)(((LinearLayout)((LinearLayout)tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(1)).getChildAt(1));
tv2.setScaleY(-1);
TextView tv3 = (TextView)(((LinearLayout)((LinearLayout)tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(2)).getChildAt(1));
tv3.setScaleY(-1);
```

[image: Sample screenshot]

Comment: @Wilhelm Thanks :)

Comment: As @Michael told in the answer below, app:tabIndicatorGravity="top" works smooth

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this by rotating the TabLayout like this:

```
tabLayout.setRotationX(180);
```

Then you must rotate all of its TextView children back, or you can set the TabLayout a custom view, instead of recursively searching for a TextView:

```
TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
tab.setCustomView(R.layout.layout_tab_view);
```

layout_tab_view.xml

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:rotationX="180"
        android:text="HOME"/>
```

I guess you loose some default functionality if you set a custom view, such as Fragment title naming from PagerAdapter and TextView disabled appearance, but you can bind that somehow together in another way.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately you cannot do it by setting an attribute or setting it in code.
[TabLayout](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.java?autodive=0%2F%2F) has a property mTabStrip of SlidingTabStrip (internal class), which is set as private final

```
private final SlidingTabStrip mTabStrip;
```

, so you cannot access it, by extending TabLayout.

So SlidingTabStrip (which extends LinearLayoyut)is a view which overrides draw method

```
@Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);
        // Thick colored underline below the current selection
        if (mIndicatorLeft >= 0 && mIndicatorRight > mIndicatorLeft) {
            canvas.drawRect(mIndicatorLeft, getHeight() - mSelectedIndicatorHeight,
                    mIndicatorRight, getHeight(), mSelectedIndicatorPaint);
        }
    }
```

So you can see that it draws the rectangle with a top and bottom properties.

May be in future they will have a flag to change it.

Answer (score 2):

I have a different approach for doing that..

1. Set the tab indicator color same as the background color of the tab layout (So that you will not see the tab indicator at bottom)
2. Add a linear layout (horizontal) just above the tab layout containing views (same number as equal to number of tabs).

`<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/tab_bg"
    android:weightSum="3">`

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_tab_indicator_white"/>

<View
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_tab_indicator_blue"/>

<View
    android:id="@+id/view3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_tab_indicator_blue"/>
```

`</LinearLayout>`

3. Now just programmatically adjust the view backgrounds.

   `viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
          @Override
       public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {`

   ```
   }

   @Override
   public void onPageSelected(int position) {
       setTitle(getPageTitle(position));

       switch(position){

           case 0:
               view1.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.selector_tab_indicator_white );
               view2.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.selector_tab_indicator_blue );
               view3.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.selector_tab_indicator_blue );
               break;

           case 1:
               view1.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.selector_tab_indicator_blue );
               view2.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.selector_tab_indicator_white );
               view3.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.selector_tab_indicator_blue );
               break;

           case 2:
               view1.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.selector_tab_indicator_blue );
               view2.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.selector_tab_indicator_blue );
               view3.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.selector_tab_indicator_white );
               break;

           default:
               view1.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.selector_tab_indicator_white );
               view2.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.selector_tab_indicator_blue );
               view3.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.selector_tab_indicator_blue );
               break;
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

   }
   ```

   `});`

Use these selectors for customising the views

selector_tab_indicator_white.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
<corners
    android:radius="50dp"/>
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#c4c0c0" />
<solid
    android:color="#fafafa" />
```

selector_tab_indicator_blue.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
<corners
    android:radius="0dp"/>
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/tab_bg" />
<solid
    android:color="@color/tab_bg" />
```

The Result:
[image]

Comment: What if I have five tabs with different sizes?

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot - Use a linear layout instead. But there will not be any animation while changing the tabs.

Comment: kartik agarval solution worked for me. you solution not working for uneven space of tabs.

Answer (score 2):

You only need those lines

```
tabLayout.setRotationX(180);

    tabListed = ((LinearLayout)tabLayout.getChildAt(0));
    for(int position = 0;position<tabListed.getChildCount();position++) {
        LinearLayout item=((LinearLayout) tabListed.getChildAt(position));
        item.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.square_tab));
        item.setRotationX(180);
    }
```

First tab rotation turn tab layout 180º  then you will get all tabs and them turn it 180º. So they be good again.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done by xml attribute, but can be done via setting image in background of tab with filled colour at top and transparent at bottom.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
          ...
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/bg_tab"
            ...
 />
```

bg_tab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/cap" android:state_selected="true" />
</selector>
```

cap.png

[image]

transparent at bottom

Answer (score 1):

I know this question was asked 2 years ago, but I didn't find any simple solution without using any library (smartTabLayout doesn't have SelectedTextColour property).

invert your tabLayout to get the indicator at the top
`android:rotationX="180"`
now this will cause the text in that tab to be inverted as well, so to counter that
we'll have to create custom Tab view. Make an xml file eg: layout_custom_tab

```
<TextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/tab.text"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:maxLines="1"
android:padding="10dp"
android:rotationX="180"
android:textAllCaps="true"
android:textSize="12sp"
android:textColor="@color/white"
/>
```

Note: you don't need RelativeLayout or anyting else when there is just one element

create your own TabLayout 
and set the customView to it.

```
public class TabLayoutPlus extends TabLayout {

public TabLayoutPlus(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public TabLayoutPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public TabLayoutPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
public void setupWithViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    super.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    this.removeAllTabs();

    PagerAdapter adapter = viewPager.getAdapter();

    for (int i = 0, count = adapter.getCount(); i < count; i++) {
        Tab tab = this.newTab();
        View customView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_custom_tab, null);
        TextViewPlus tv = (TextViewPlus) customView.findViewById(R.id.tab_text);
        tv.setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i));
        tab.setCustomView(customView);
        this.addTab(tab.setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i)));
    }
 }    
}
```

your TabLayout in your activity will look like this

```
<TabLayoutPlus
    android:id="@+id/tablayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/camera.buttons.layout"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@color/cardscan.background"
    android:rotationX="180"
    app:tabGravity="center"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
    />
```

if you need to highlight Selected tab text colour

```
private void setSelectedTab(TabLayoutPlus.Tab tab) {
    View view = tab.getCustomView();
    TextViewPlus tabtext = (TextViewPlus) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_text);
    tabtext.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary)); // color you want to highlight your text with
}

private void setUnselectedTab(TabLayoutPlus.Tab tab){
    View view = tab.getCustomView();
    TextViewPlus tabtext = (TextViewPlus) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_text);
    tabtext.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white)); // color you want to lowlight your text with
}
```

Now just add OnTabSelectedListener

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            setSelectedTab(tab);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            setUnselectedTab(tab);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            setSelectedTab(tab);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved using this method

set scaleY="-1" , this will rotate TabLayout to 180 degrees, as a result tab layout rotated reverse with text and rotate your TextView to Horizontally to 180 degrees, that will solve the problem, see the code below

1. activity.xml

   ```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">


       <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">


           <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
               android:id="@+id/viewpager_exp"
               android:layout_above="@+id/tabs_RL"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />



           <RelativeLayout
               android:id="@+id/tabs_RL"
               android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="@dimen/footer_height">


               <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                   android:id="@+id/tabs"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_60"
                   android:background="@color/white"
                   android:clipToPadding="false"
                   android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                   android:paddingRight="0dp"
                   android:scaleY="-1"
                   app:layout_scrollFlags="snap|enterAlways"
                   app:tabGravity="fill"
                   app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
                   app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
                   app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/dark_pink1"
                   app:tabMinWidth="50dp"
                   app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
                   app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
                   app:tabMode="fixed" />

           </RelativeLayout>
       </RelativeLayout>

   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
2. custom_tab.xml

   ```
   <customviews.CusMediumTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/tab"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
   android:textColor="#000000"
   android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_12"
   android:rotationX="180"
   android:textStyle="bold" />
   ```
3. MainActivity.class

   ```
       tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

       tabOne = (CusMediumTextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
       tabOne.setText("Tab1");
       tabOne.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_black));
       tabOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.home_icon, 0, 0);


       tabTwo = (CusMediumTextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
       tabTwo.setText("Tab2");
       tabTwo.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_black));
       tabTwo.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.settin_icon, 0, 0);


       tabThree = (CusMediumTextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
       tabThree.setText("Tab3");
       tabThree.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_black));
       tabThree.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( 0,R.drawable.delete_icon, 0, 0);


       tabFour = (CusMediumTextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
       tabFour.setText("Tab4");
       tabFour.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_black));
       tabFour.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( 0, R.drawable.msg_icon,0, 0);

       tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);
       tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tabTwo);
       tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setCustomView(tabThree);
       tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setCustomView(tabFour);
   ```