# how can i add this gray line in the Tablayout? Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, material-ui

[image]

I need to add a gray line like this at the top of the TabLayout

Actual code:

````
            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tl_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/tab_indicator_height"
                android:background="?attr/colorBackground"
                app:isVisible="@{viewModel.shouldShowTabLayout}"
                app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="@dimen/tab_indicator_height"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabPaddingStart="@dimen/margin_side"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="?attr/colorOnSurface"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@style/Body1" />
```
````

Comment: You can find the solution in this answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/52870455/5097931](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52870455/5097931)

Comment: tnks but i need to add a gray line like the picture :( heelp

Comment: You can add `View`  with gray background on top of `TabLayout`.

Comment: tnks thats work